# Download a file with HTTP "Authorization" header set

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rest, download

I am providing a file upload to a resource in my RESTful API (made with Rails). When you `GET /resource/123/attachment` the file with corresponding MIME type is sent to the browser. (can be anything .. an image, a PDF, a text file, whatsoever)

If it is of any interest, it's done like this:

```
send_file(contract.attachment.path, :filename => contract.attachment.original_filename)
```

But since the uploaded files are user-based and confidential, you need to set the `Authorization` HTTP header with the token.

So I thought about using `jQuery.get` so that I can set the HTTP header. But how do I handle the response coming from the server? It should behave like you clicked a normal link (only that a HTTP header is set before requesting)

Comment: Is token based solution (instead of http header) acceptable for you? I mean GET /resource/123/attachement?token=111222333444

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the server output and the images are not too big you can base64 the images and do something like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url : '/resource/123/attachment', 
  processData : false,
}).done(function(data){
  $("#YOUR_IMG_ID").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+data);
});
```

Another option is that you could write in an alternate authentication to allow you to put something in the querystring like <img src="/resource/123/attachment?auth=xxxxx">.  For example you could look into oAuth or something to sign the request.